# How to make full export products in Magento (algorithm)

Tags: magento, export, product

I need build valid algorithm to make export all products in CSV file.

Problem is just existing **Simple** products on the current installed Magento import to new Magento like **Configurable** products.

What is full algorithm to this process?

I was made export/import all existing Categories already.

What to do next? Maybe i should import/export all attributes (attributes sets) to save all dependencies between products and attributes in new installed Magento?

And finally what to do with **Custom options** in Simple products. This Custom options should be used like Simple Products to Configurable products on export products in new Magento.

Thnx!

Comment: What version of Magento do you use? This functionality is out of box at Magento. Try System->Import/Export->Export.

Comment: Old version Magento 1.4 and new version 1.7. I think what in import/export system from box of Magento not supports export products with Custom options. All this Custom options I want to use like simple products to Configurable products